# Joomla Java script

Tags: javascript, joomla, conflict

Can anyone help please, I'm trying to add a simple ease  JavaScript code to Joomla but is giving conflicts with my t3 template. In addition, does anyone has any tips to avoid this conflict please.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').hide();

    $('.container').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.image').slideUp(); 
            $(this).find('.text').slideDown();
        },function () {
           $(this).find('.text').slideUp();
           $(this).find('.image').slideDown();
        }
    );
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestion to avoid conflicts.

1. Try to avoid including `jQuery CDN` multiple times.
2. Check if you have `jQuery` library already included in the site through source code.
3. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` as selectors in the code to avoid conflicts. Because Joomla also uses `mootools`.js and `mootools` uses `$` as selector that may cause conflict if you uses in `jQuery`.
4. Adding the `JavaScript` code to bottom of the page may resolve the problem.
5. Use `jQuery.noConflict()` to resolve conflicts.

ex.

```
<script>
J = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code
});
</script>
```